# Attach Multiple files via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me edit below script to add multiple files listed on 3rd column (Column C) of the spreadsheet?

My current macro looks for one file at a time and sends out individual emails. I need it to look for multiple files name (in listed folder path) listed in column C (3rd Column) and it does this until it reaches the empty cell.

### My current scrip is below where you will see it looks for one file at a time.

```
Sub AttachandSendEmail()
Dim obMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim irow As Integer
Dim dpath As String
Dim pfile As String

'file path
dpath = "C:\Users\filelocation"

'looping through all the files and sending an mail

irow = 1

Do While Cells(irow, 3) <> Empty


'pikcing up file name from column C
 pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 3) & "*")


'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then

    Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With obMail
        .To = "email@comapny.com"
        .Subject = "O/S Blanace"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Body = "Please see attached files"
        .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
        .Send
    End With

End If

'go to next file listed on the C column
 irow = irow + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it sends one message with all files attached.

```
Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With obMail
    .To = "email@comapny.com"
    .Subject = "O/S Blanace"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = "Please see attached files"

    Do While Cells(irow, 3) <> Empty
        'pikcing up file name from column C
        pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 3) & "*")
        'checking for file exist in a folder and if its a pdf file

        If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
            .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
        End If

        'go to next file listed on the C column
        irow = irow + 1
    Loop

    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Hi @Michał Turczyn.  Is that possible to pick any file? such as pdf & excel?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `If` statement, where you check extension of a file...

Comment: Turczyn Is that possible to change the file name picking up location from Column "C" to "A24" and onward?